# Implement pipe on dynamic AngularJS 4 Table

Tags: angular, filter, html-table, pipe

I'm trying to implement a pipe for filter all columns. I have a code with this plnkr.
https://plnkr.co/edit/jZKJl9yDnXCvGCnxqlHM
This is the code of my component:

```
   import {Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core'


@Component({
  selector: 'my-table',
  template: `
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let header of headers">
          {{ header }}
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
        <td *ngFor="let cell of objectKeys(row)">
          {{ row[cell] }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  `,
})
export class MyTableComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() data: any[];
  headers: any;
  private objectKeys: any;

  constructor() {
    this.objectKeys = Object.keys;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.headers = Object.keys(this.data[0]);
  }
}
```

I want to implement a pipe for filtering all columns but I can't get it through. Any idea?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "pipe"?

Comment: @nicooga i mean a filter pipe. like "let record of records | filter : filterString".